# Read/Write to Debug Port (0x80h) using C#

Tags: c#, io, x86, port, motherboard

I'm trying to write a simple C# program on Windows to display a character or digit on the Debug Port (address at: 0x80h, also known as the POST code display) of any supported motherboard (as shown [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005500/boards-and-kits.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gRLJmiawnA)). This has already been done before in Linux, C, Assembly, and via a freeware called "[TempLCD](https://sigyn.dataghost.com/TempLCD/)":

C ([__outword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/outword?view=msvc-160) command example): [What does the 0x80 port address connect to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793899/what-does-the-0x80-port-address-connect-to)

Assembly: [Is there a way to manually change BIOS POST codes on motherboard LCD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937983/is-there-a-way-to-manually-change-bios-post-codes-on-motherboard-lcd)

Linux: [Writing LCD Temperatures in Linux to Debug Port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453486/writing-cpu-temperature-to-port-0x80-bios-debug-card-with-bash-script)

In this screenshot, you can see the debug port at 80 (Device Manager > View > Resource by type):
[image: Device Manager with Port 80]

How can I target this port for read/writes using any high-level programming language, such as C#? The [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class fails, since it expects COM1, COM2, etc.

Comment: You can't do this directly from a user mode program - you'll need a kernel mode driver. There's probably a generic one available that you could use but I am not aware of one that would work off the top of my head.

Comment: Normally your development board is connected to another PC using a USB to USB cable.  You write to com port (Com1 or Com2) on the development board and then read on PC on a Com port.  You do not use the I/O address.  There is a driver on both the development board and PC which maps the I/O address to the name of the port (Com1, Com2, ...).

Comment: TempLCD uses both a DLL file and driver.sys file named: WinRing0x64. Could this possibly be the jump from ring 3 to ring 0 that's needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only write to this I/O port in *kernel* mode. Read/writes to these I/O ports are not supported in a normal user-mode application.

You can see even in the solutions to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793899/what-does-the-0x80-port-address-connect-to) that these all require a kernel-mode driver. In particular, the Windows solution [`__outword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/outword) is just a MSVC-specific intrinsic that causes [the x86 `OUT` instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_222.html) to be emitted, and, as the Intel x86 documentation says, [`OUT` is a privileged instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576612/are-the-out-and-in-instructions-privileged-instructions) that is not allowed to be executed in Ring 3 (which is where user-mode applications are run).

Since it can't be executed from user mode, it cannot be executed at all from a .NET application. You cannot use .NET to write a Windows driver that runs in Ring 0. You will need to use a different programming language that can generate native (i.e., unmanaged) code. C and C++ are the typical choices.

If you wrote the driver in an unmanaged language like C or C++, you could then call it from a C# application using the P/Invoke (`DllImport`) mechanism. See: [Accessing Device Drivers from C#](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/accessing-device-drivers-from-c/184416423) and similar resources.

Comment: Technically it is up to the OS design to allow or allow/disallow access to ports in usermode (ring 3).  You can set IOPL to 3 for usermode and the IN/OUT instructions will execute without raising an exception. Alternatively you can use an IO Bitmap in the TSS to grant/deny individual port access with IOPL=0 to give access to specific ports. Linux for example use to have the `iopl` function and still has `ioperm`